# Let $A =\Bbb N − \{n^2 : n \in\Bbb N\}$. Construct a bijection from $A$ to $\Bbb N$.

Tags: functions

To solve this function, I was thinking to use an index if that's possible:

$f(x) = (i = 1$ if $x = 2$
--------$(i +1$ if $x_n = x_{n-1} + 2$
--------$(xi/x$

I see no other way to keep increasing the differences between the preimage and the image of $f$ after $A$ skips over another number whose square root is in $\Bbb N$.

Comment: I have some idea of what you were trying to do with $f(x)$, but as it stands, it’s incomprehensible. Perhaps you should try explaining in words instead.

Comment: It would help tremendously to make your post more readable if you were to properly format the post using MathJax and $\LaTeX$.  Information on doing so [can be found here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  I assume you mean to say $A=\Bbb N\setminus \{n^2~:~n\in\Bbb N\}$, i.e. $A$ is the set of non-square natural numbers?  The fact that they are in bijection is trivial due to $A\subset \Bbb N$ and $A$ is infinite in size.  Finding an explicit bijection without describing it with words can be tedious.

Comment: If it were me, I would simply use $f:\Bbb N \to A$ defined as $f(n) = \text{the}~n^{\text{th}}~\text{non-square natural number}$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844998/the-set-of-natural-numbers-that-dont-belong-to-a-set.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out such a function is not *terrible* to write with math symbols.

For a non-square natural number, $n$, we ask the side question of how many perfect square numbers are in fact smaller than it.  Well, the largest square number smaller than it would be $(\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)^2$ and there would be a total of $\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor$ square numbers smaller than it.  (*Convince yourself of this fact*)

E.g. the number $11$ has $\lfloor \sqrt{11}\rfloor \approx \lfloor 3.3166\rfloor=3$ square numbers smaller than it.  Indeed $\color{red}{1},2,3,\color{red}{4},5,6,7,8,\color{red}{9},10,11$, the three numbers colored red are those three square numbers smaller than it that were promised.

So, of the $n$ numbers smaller or equal to the number $n$, you have $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$ of them shouldn't have been counted.  You have then $n-\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$ gives the number of non-square natural numbers less than or equal to $n$.

I.e. letting $f~:~\Bbb N\to A$ be defined as $f(n) = \text{the}~n^\text{th}~\text{non-square natural number}$

you have $f^{-1}(a)~:~A\to\Bbb N$ is given as $f^{-1}(a)=a-\lfloor\sqrt{a}\rfloor$

Writing $f$ with symbols instead of words remains a challenge (*without brute forcing it using set notation*)

Answer (score 0):

Extended HINT: You want an explicit bijection from $A$ to $\Bbb N$. I’m going to assume that your $\Bbb N$ is my $\Bbb Z^+$, i.e., that it does not include $0$; if it does, you’ll have to modify this a little.

Let’s look at the first few values of the function $f$ that I think you have in mind, along with one other number that will prove useful:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
n:&2&3&5&6&7&8&10&11&12&13&14&15&17\\
f(n):&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13\\
n-f(n):&1&1&2&2&2&2&3&3&3&3&3&3&4
\end{array}$$

Notice that $n-f(n)$ increases by $1$ every time $A$ skips a square: for instance, $8-f(8)=2$, but $10-f(10)=3$. If you look a bit closer, you might notice that $n-f(n)$ is the number of perfect squares that are less than $n$. The only square less than $2$ or $3$ is $1^2$; the $2$ squares that are less than $5,6,7$, and $8$ are $1^2$ and $2^2$; and so on. This suggests that

$$f(n)=n-\text{the number of squares less than }n\;.$$

- Try to explain why this must in fact be true if we simply use $f$ to enumerate $A$ in increasing order.
- Then try to use the floor function $\lfloor x\rfloor$ (which you may know as the greatest integer function, perhaps with the older notation $[x]$) to express the number of squares less than $n$ in terms of $n$.