# The set of natural numbers that don't belong to a set

Tags: number-theory

> Describe which natural numbers do not belong to the set $$E = \left\{\left[n+\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2}\right] \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}.$$

The answer is the set of positive perfect squares. I am not sure how to prove it. We know that $\left[n+\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2}\right] = n+\left[\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2} \right]$, but what do I do from here?

Comment: $[\cdot]$ is the floor function?

Comment: @GFauxPas  I think that that is a floor function.  Setting n=1 returns 2.

Comment: Side note:  These days, it's more conventional to denote the floor function by $\lfloor x\rfloor$, with syntax "\lfloor x\rfloor".  That lets you write $\lceil x\rceil$ for the least integer not less than $x$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I don't see how the set of numbers not being in $E$ is the set of perfect squares is false.

Comment: @NoahSchweber  Not following...the OP is looking for those natural numbers which are not in $E$.  Quick check seemed to confirm the statement...do you have a counterexample?

Comment: @JohnRyan Sorry, I misread. $E$'s complement might indeed be the set of perfect squares.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/850483/11619). Looks like a duplicate. As I happened to answer that question I'm leaving closing (whichever direction is judged best) to others.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(n):=n+\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2}$ and $g(n):=\big\lfloor f(n)\big\rfloor$ for each $n=1,2,\ldots$.  Observe that $f(n)$ is not an integer for any positive integer $n$.  We have $1<f(n+1)-f(n)<2$, so that $$1\leq g(n+1)-g(n)\leq 2$$
for all $n=1,2,\ldots$.  Suppose that $g(n+1)-g(n)=2$.  Write $k:=g(n)$.  Therefore, $k<f(n)<k+1$ and $k+2<f(n+1)<k+3$, or
$$n+\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2}<k+1\text{ and }(n+1)+\sqrt{n+1}+\frac{1}{2}>k+2\,.$$
Hence, 
$$\left(\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2<k+\frac{3}{4}\text{ and }\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2>k+\frac{7}{4}\,.$$
Therefore,
$$\sqrt{n}<\sqrt{k+\frac{3}{4}}-\frac{1}{2}\text{ and }\sqrt{n+1}>\sqrt{k+\frac{7}{4}}-\frac{1}{2}\,.$$
Ergo,
$$k+1-\sqrt{k+\frac{7}{4}}<n<k+1-\sqrt{k+\frac{3}{4}}$$
If $m:=k+1-n$, then 
$$m^2-2<m^2-\frac{7}{4}<k<m^2-\frac{3}{4}<m^2\,.$$
Therefore, $k=m^2-1$.  This shows that $g(n)=m^2-1$ and $g(n+1)=m^2+1$.  Hence, we have established that, if a positive integer $x$ is not in $E$, then $x$ is a perfect square.

We shall now prove that no perfect square positive integer is in $E$.  Clearly, $1\notin E$.  For $l=1,2,\ldots$, we observe that
$$f\left(l^2+l\right)=l^2+l+\sqrt{l^2+l}+\frac{1}{2}<l^2+l+\sqrt{l^2+l+\frac{1}{4}}+\frac{1}{2}=l^2+2l+1$$
and that
$$f\left(l^2+l+1\right)=l^2+l+1+\sqrt{l^2+l+1}+\frac{1}{2}>l^2+l+1+\sqrt{l^2+l+\frac{1}{4}}+\frac{1}{2}=l^2+2l+2\,.$$
Therefore, $g\left(l^2+l\right)=l^2+2l=(l+1)^2-1$ and $g\left(l^2+l+1\right)=l^2+2l+2=(l+1)^2+1$.  Hence, $(l+1)^2\notin E$ for every $l=1,2,\ldots$.  The proof is now complete.

Answer (score 0):

when does $\lfloor \sqrt n + \frac 12\rfloor$ jump?

$(k+0.5)^2  = k^2 + k + 0.25$

when $n$ can be written as $k^2 + k$ you are on the low side of the next step, and when $n$ can be written as $k^2 + k + 1$ you are on the high side of a step.

$\lfloor k^2 + k +\sqrt {k^2 + k} + \frac 12\rfloor = k^2 + 2k\\
\lfloor k^2 + k + 1+\sqrt {k^2 + k + 1} + \frac 12\rfloor = k^2 + 2k + 2\\
$

And, $(k^2 + 2k + 1) = (k+1)^2$ gets skipped.

Comment: Show that $n = k^2 + l, -k+1\le l \le k \to k^2 + k + l$ covers the natural numbers greater than $k^2$ and less then $(k+1)^2$