# Almost-Linear Sequence of Positive Integers Excluding a Near-Quadratic Integer Sequence

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, quadratics, integers, set-partition

I remember that I have seen a similar problem to this one here: [The set of natural numbers that don't belong to a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844998/the-set-of-natural-numbers-that-dont-belong-to-a-set) (which is a duplicate of [$m$ doesn't come in the sequence $a_n=[n+\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2}]$ iff m is a perfect square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850483/m-doesnt-come-in-the-sequence-a-n-n-sqrtn-frac12-iff-m-is-a-perfe)).  If my memory serves me right, that problem was about a sequence excluding triangular numbers, and the sequence was given by something of the form $n\mapsto\left\lfloor n+\sqrt{an+b}+c\right\rfloor$ for some rational numbers $a,b,c$.  Does anybody know anything about such problems (such as where these problems are form, or whether there are other similar problems)?  I believe that I have also seen other similar problems.  Hence, I am trying to establish something akin to a quadratic version of [Beatty's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence).

In this post, $\mathbb{N}$ denotes the set of positive integers (i.e., $0\notin\mathbb{N}$).  Let $p:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be a *near-quadratic function*, that is, $p$ is a strictly increasing function given by $$p(n):=\left\lfloor\alpha n^2+\beta n+\gamma\right\rfloor \tag{*}$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$ with $\alpha>0$ which is called the *leading coefficient* of $p$.  (Note that, if $\beta>1-3\alpha$, then it is guaranteed that $p$ is strictly increasing.)  Also, an *almost-linear function* $q:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is defined as $$q(n):=\left\lfloor n+\sqrt{an+b}+c\right\rfloor\tag{**}$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a>0$.  We say that two functions $p:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ and $q:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ are *complementary functions* iff $$\big\{p(n)\,\boldsymbol{\big{|}}\,n\in\mathbb{N}\big\}\text{ and }\big\{q(n)\,\boldsymbol{\big{|}}\,n\in\mathbb{N}\big\}$$ form a partition of the set of positive integers $\mathbb{N}$.

> **Question:** What are all the near-quadratic functions $p:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that there exists a complementary function $q:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ which is almost-linear?  What is an example of a near-quadratic function $p$ with a complementary function $q$ such that the leading coefficient $\alpha$ of $p$  is irrational?   Which $\alpha>0$ can be the leading coefficient of a near-quadratic function $p$ with a complementary function $q$?

According to Jyrki Lahtonen's suggestion, it can be shown that, if (*) and (**) are complementary, then $$a\alpha=1\,.$$  From this result, I have recovered a sequence skipping triangular numbers: $n\mapsto \left\lfloor n+\sqrt{2n}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$.  I have not proven this claim, but I am positive it is correct.

---

**Partial Answer:**  It appears that, for a fixed $k\in\mathbb{N}$, if $p:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is given by $$p(n)=\left\lfloor\dfrac{k}{2}n^2-\frac{(k-2)}{2}n+\frac{k-1}{8}\right\rfloor$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $q:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ defined via$$q(n)=\left\lfloor n+\sqrt{\frac{2}{k}n}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is a complementary function to $p$.

It also appears that, for a fixed $k\in\mathbb{N}$, if $p:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is given by
$$p(n):=\left\lfloor\frac{1}{k}n^2+\frac{(k-1)}{k}n\right\rfloor$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $q:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ defined via
$$q(n):=\left\lfloor n+\sqrt{kn}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is complementary to $p$.   I have not yet tried to prove any of these assertions.

Comment: You can also try and adapt the technique I used [in a duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/850528/11619). If $a>0$, then $q(n+1)>q(n)$. Also, at $n\approx am^2$ we have $q(n)-n\approx am$, so before the point $n=am^2$ approximately $am$ numbers have been "skipped" by the sequence $q(n)$. Identifying that sparse set of skipped values is probably not too difficult. Don't know if we can find a matching $q$ for all $p$s, sorry.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you.  You just gave me a proof that $a\alpha=1$.